# shiny - renderImage does not work

Tags: r, image, path, shiny, render

I have a shinyApp that, at some point, use a function 'pathview' to generate a png image in the working directory. I want to use renderImage to dispay it in the App, but it seems that shiny looks into a directory of temp files (it's the case for another image generated with another function, which works). How can I specify the correct path to renderImage ?

Here is the concerned code (The original App is longer, I isolated the concerned part - it should work on your computers), bu you need the input data (copy-pasted at the end of the question, hope it will work).

Thanks !

Here is the code (had some trouble to paste it here - I hope indents will stay corrects) :

```
library(clusterProfiler)# v3.2.11
library(shiny) # v1.0.0
library(pathview) # v1.14
# Bioconductor 3.4


###  Page ###


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Pathways Enrichment Analysis"),
  wellPanel(fileInput("data", "Choose a txt file", multiple=FALSE, accept = NULL)),

  mainPanel(

  ##### Inputs #####    
    tabsetPanel(      
    ### Data
      tabPanel("Data", id="data", dataTableOutput("contents")),      
    ### Pathways
      tabPanel("Pathways analysis", id="fkegg",
           sliderInput(inputId="keggp", label="P-value cut-off", value=0.01, min=0.001, max=0.05 ),
           sliderInput(inputId="keggq", label="q-value cut-off", value=0.01, min=0.001, max=0.05 ),
           selectInput(inputId="adjmk", label="p-value adjustment method", c("holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "bonferroni", "BH", "BY", "fdr", "none")),
           actionButton("startkegg", "Start")
      )
    ),

    ##### Outputs  #####    
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Pathways results", id="rkegg", plotOutput("pathway1"))
    )
  ) 
) 


###  SERVER ###


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ### Data ###################
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$data)) {return(NULL)}
    read.table(input$data$datapath, header = TRUE, dec=",")
  })

  output$contents <- renderDataTable(data(), options=list(pageLength=10))

  ### Pathways ###################

  genes <- reactive({as.character(data()$Ensembl_Gene_ID)})
  entrezIDs <- reactive({ bitr(genes(), fromType="ENSEMBL" , toType="ENTREZID", OrgDb="org.Hs.eg.db")$ENTREZID})

  observe({
    if (input$startkegg != 0) {

    kegg <- reactive({ enrichKEGG(entrezIDs(), pAdjustMethod=input$adjmk, pvalueCutoff=input$keggp, qvalueCutoff=input$keggq)})

    output$pathway1 <- renderImage({
      width  <- session$clientData$output_pathway1_width
      height <- session$clientData$output_pathway1_height
      outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')

      png(outfile)
      pathview(gene.data=entrezIDs(), pathway.id=as.matrix(as.data.frame(kegg())[1])[1:1],species = "hsa", limit=3)
      # Pathview generates a png file (it is possible to generate many png at once by changing '[1:1]' by other numbers)
      dev.off()

      list(src = outfile,
         contentType = 'image/png+xml',
         width = width,
         height = height,
         alt = "plotGoGraph")
      }, deleteFile  =FALSE)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here are the input data (not full, only a half of it-  it works too):

```
Ensembl_Gene_ID Gene_Symbol log2FC  p_value adj_pvalue
ENSG00000090339 ICAM1   6,6698404077    0   0
ENSG00000108691 CCL2    6,3927430651    0   0
ENSG00000118503 TNFAIP3 4,1752383048    0   0
ENSG00000162692 VCAM1   9,0516122689    0   0
ENSG00000185215 TNFAIP2 3,3128766885    0   0
ENSG00000169429 IL8 3,4854038547    1,49E-291   4,76E-288
ENSG00000077150 NFKB2   3,6760936413    9,72E-277   2,82E-273
ENSG00000100906 NFKBIA  2,8107738915    1,69E-238   4,50E-235
ENSG00000161011 SQSTM1  1,404984023 6,60E-87    3,91E-84
ENSG00000164251 F2RL1   2,228720453 7,80E-174   1,25E-170
ENSG00000145365 TIFA    2,4827316786    9,05E-190   1,61E-186
ENSG00000056558 TRAF1   4,3219219715    0   0
ENSG00000104856 RELB    5,3740452546    0   0
ENSG00000007908 SELE    6,5992071817    0   0
ENSG00000023445 BIRC3   7,1013231569    0   0
ENSG00000128284 APOL3   3,0580886345    5,34E-219   1,31E-215
ENSG00000184371 CSF1    2,8747119649    1,34E-200   2,51E-197
ENSG00000160326 SLC2A6  2,371736578 7,25E-153   9,27E-150
ENSG00000112149 CD83    5,1849020913    6,25E-209   1,25E-205
ENSG00000169248 CXCL11  3,9885010193    3,59E-153   4,78E-150
ENSG00000163735 CXCL5   5,3189628206    6,02E-161   8,75E-158
ENSG00000006210 CX3CL1  6,2047905222    2,06E-142   2,53E-139
ENSG00000185101 ANO9    5,5319492083    6,65E-119   6,25E-116
ENSG00000227507 LTB 4,5693401008    8,35E-99    5,93E-96
ENSG00000086061 DNAJA1  0,6160659876    8,81E-20    1,04E-17
ENSG00000145632 PLK2    0,3743843813    3,41E-08    1,54E-06
ENSG00000137575 SDCBP   0,5110720979    1,04E-13    8,15E-12
ENSG00000185551 NR2F2   -0,4961472049   2,83E-13    2,15E-11
ENSG00000143878 RHOB    0,3760342184    1,01E-07    4,24E-06
ENSG00000163661 PTX3    0,7264569628    3,04E-18    3,32E-16
ENSG00000143321 HDGF    0,3691856958    2,76E-07    1,08E-05
ENSG00000166710 B2M 0,546357382 2,92E-12    2,01E-10
ENSG00000091527 CDV3    0,3818032113    4,70E-08    2,08E-06
ENSG00000167996 FTH1    0,2597510103    0,0013737609    0,0215751345
ENSG00000104951 IL4I1   3,4292833296    1,11E-140   1,27E-137
ENSG00000142871 CYR61   0,2496820627    0,0001860959    0,0039336139
ENSG00000172602 RND1    3,1459477897    1,09E-128   1,12E-125
ENSG00000008517 IL32    2,6720847487    6,15E-172   9,36E-169
ENSG00000049249 TNFRSF9 8,1430466274    1,04E-105   8,28E-103
ENSG00000188015 S100A3  4,0520465746    6,83E-108   5,60E-105
ENSG00000163739 CXCL1   3,2317419311    2,29E-210   4,88E-207
ENSG00000110848 CD69    3,9921576403    5,45E-104   4,15E-101
ENSG00000164932 CTHRC1  1,8587056384    4,35E-105   3,39E-102
ENSG00000124875 CXCL6   3,5080734691    2,70E-188   4,54E-185
ENSG00000115919 KYNU    3,8834279178    1,61E-103   1,20E-100
ENSG00000115009 CCL20   5,9380301295    1,03E-111   8,85E-109
ENSG00000159840 ZYX 0,221308813 0,0017025307    0,0255678561
ENSG00000234745 HLA-B   2,2802098006    8,97E-113   8,19E-110
ENSG00000160223 ICOSLG  3,4416028095    1,03E-218   2,34E-215
ENSG00000163545 NUAK2   3,2891894371    7,64E-96    4,98E-93
ENSG00000169245 CXCL10  8,4054198187    1,83E-94    1,17E-91
ENSG00000069493 CLEC2D  3,5342574865    1,45E-78    7,74E-76
ENSG00000204592 HLA-E   0,616047908 1,69E-15    1,49E-13
ENSG00000145901 TNIP1   2,0278859147    5,11E-158   7,11E-155
ENSG00000104312 RIPK2   1,48650534  3,65E-82    2,12E-79
ENSG00000123240 OPTN    1,7975448821    8,58E-123   8,57E-120
ENSG00000253522 MIR146A 3,3553807205    2,68E-72    1,28E-69
ENSG00000168394 TAP1    2,102288878 1,51E-131   1,61E-128
ENSG00000146232 NFKBIE  2,3570285443    3,87E-112   3,44E-109
ENSG00000205502 C2CD4B  2,9440001323    6,26E-74    3,18E-71
ENSG00000167100 SAMD14  1,9532366462    6,55E-69    2,91E-66
ENSG00000113504 SLC12A7 1,4720046424    9,48E-80    5,22E-77
ENSG00000100401 RANGAP1 0,6857346473    6,76E-20    8,09E-18
ENSG00000100767 PAPLN   2,3421900636    1,39E-78    7,52E-76
ENSG00000058085 LAMC2   1,5431664983    2,86E-53    1,04E-50
ENSG00000270607 RP11-359E10.1   2,3854036344    1,47E-70    6,72E-68
ENSG00000107201 DDX58   1,4595388552    1,70E-73    8,48E-71
ENSG00000081041 CXCL2   3,0262033543    7,41E-43    2,09E-40
ENSG00000163132 MSX1    2,7761598722    1,29E-66    5,51E-64
ENSG00000028277 POU2F2  2,0466146728    3,97E-65    1,65E-62
ENSG00000050730 TNIP3   3,229329092 1,37E-44    4,10E-42
ENSG00000128335 APOL2   1,473090214 2,09E-70    9,41E-68
ENSG00000237988 OR2I1P  7,8419334093    3,18E-67    1,37E-64
ENSG00000105246 EBI3    5,0935025027    1,23E-59    4,89E-57
ENSG00000124145 SDC4    1,407771963 6,90E-76    3,55E-73
ENSG00000115267 IFIH1   2,6863181071    9,94E-139   1,10E-135
ENSG00000112096 SOD2    1,7840242915    7,44E-121   7,21E-118
ENSG00000126561 STAT5A  1,382924375 6,59E-72    3,10E-69
ENSG00000144476 ACKR3   1,5463153496    1,10E-43    3,14E-41
ENSG00000132481 TRIM47  1,8400193127    3,47E-94    2,17E-91
ENSG00000115604 IL18R1  1,7758792324    4,38E-102   3,18E-99
ENSG00000064042 LIMCH1  -1,697667608    1,06E-57    4,09E-55
ENSG00000075223 SEMA3C  2,6428794379    4,87E-34    1,04E-31
ENSG00000271856 RP11-861A13.4   5,3162419344    7,11E-64    2,91E-61
ENSG00000107282 APBA1   -1,4667390864   1,85E-36    4,38E-34
ENSG00000163131 CTSS    2,6929454478    4,65E-111   3,91E-108
ENSG00000120337 TNFSF18 1,5716255441    8,91E-90    5,48E-87
ENSG00000166387 PPFIBP2 -1,3608246629   7,19E-36    1,62E-33
ENSG00000213859 KCTD11  1,0580714969    1,04E-23    1,52E-21
ENSG00000085831 TTC39A  2,4578133228    9,15E-25    1,41E-22
ENSG00000163513 TGFBR2  0,4969789653    3,46E-09    1,81E-07
ENSG00000139174 PRICKLE1    -1,4142683759   3,02E-73    1,48E-70
ENSG00000184530 C6orf58 6,0201724937    1,58E-51    5,42E-49
ENSG00000179862 CITED4  1,3708051503    1,16E-22    1,59E-20
ENSG00000115008 IL1A    2,6593891142    7,46E-43    2,09E-40
ENSG00000131037 EPS8L1  1,0947789046    4,79E-20    5,76E-18
ENSG00000117228 GBP1    1,2025593197    6,13E-52    2,15E-49
ENSG00000172738 TMEM217 1,9639810453    3,00E-54    1,10E-51
ENSG00000168314 MOBP    2,4845110741    2,38E-26    3,92E-24
ENSG00000134070 IRAK2   2,2955364885    2,08E-141   2,46E-138
ENSG00000198535 C2CD4A  4,577996172 1,20E-40    3,24E-38
ENSG00000163874 ZC3H12A 0,9381369244    1,78E-18    1,98E-16
ENSG00000185291 IL3RA   2,3420467737    8,82E-44    2,54E-41
ENSG00000105639 JAK3    2,495057148 1,52E-41    4,18E-39
ENSG00000171223 JUNB    2,0335078068    5,12E-81    2,87E-78
ENSG00000163347 CLDN1   2,4949072106    1,73E-27    2,96E-25
ENSG00000181656 GPR88   2,0975113695    4,44E-25    6,99E-23
ENSG00000164136 IL15    2,2652411451    6,11E-47    1,90E-44
ENSG00000178695 KCTD12  -0,7539496907   7,25E-23    9,98E-21
ENSG00000176907 C8orf4  1,6829692594    1,49E-81    8,50E-79
ENSG00000163734 CXCL3   3,0321033172    4,77E-32    9,58E-30
ENSG00000185022 MAFF    1,3309075932    1,13E-46    3,49E-44
ENSG00000163840 DTX3L   1,2171662272    6,27E-38    1,55E-35
ENSG00000240065 PSMB9   2,2505005445    4,07E-35    8,98E-33
ENSG00000204642 HLA-F   2,1177972557    2,64E-22    3,53E-20
ENSG00000125347 IRF1    1,4482064145    8,65E-58    3,37E-55
ENSG00000162772 ATF3    1,4948349223    4,86E-33    1,00E-30
ENSG00000027697 IFNGR1  1,0231240904    2,49E-36    5,76E-34
ENSG00000171408 PDE7B   -1,169170306    1,73E-29    3,09E-27
ENSG00000168685 IL7R    2,125882044 2,32E-96    1,55E-93
ENSG00000177409 SAMD9L  1,2162404685    5,73E-32    1,14E-29
ENSG00000136560 TANK    1,1525846708    7,03E-51    2,34E-48
ENSG00000109320 NFKB1   1,5459523059    6,58E-87    3,91E-84
ENSG00000139263 LRIG3   1,2088786453    2,15E-62    8,69E-60
ENSG00000161940 BCL6B   1,1369814172    6,66E-51    2,24E-48
ENSG00000108984 MAP2K6  -1,378263906    1,92E-39    4,90E-37
ENSG00000132109 TRIM21  1,0587983659    4,22E-36    9,62E-34
ENSG00000136490 LIMD2   1,1414650881    2,93E-31    5,74E-29
ENSG00000169403 PTAFR   2,166927154 6,16E-21    7,66E-19
ENSG00000128274 A4GALT  0,9518357944    6,31E-14    5,03E-12
ENSG00000083799 CYLD    1,210521761 2,05E-42    5,70E-40
ENSG00000168310 IRF2    1,2216681724    4,91E-47    1,54E-44
ENSG00000012211 PRICKLE3    0,9224797711    1,10E-15    9,98E-14
ENSG00000121858 TNFSF10 1,6268549998    2,36E-58    9,33E-56
ENSG00000111339 ART4    1,1092601697    4,43E-36    1,00E-33
ENSG00000119917 IFIT3   1,426688259 6,75E-31    1,29E-28
ENSG00000110446 SLC15A3 2,1584288816    1,45E-33    3,05E-31
ENSG00000171608 PIK3CD  1,2125359085    8,36E-40    2,17E-37
ENSG00000143387 CTSK    1,6805693689    1,85E-49    5,96E-47
ENSG00000168961 LGALS9  1,1324240248    3,44E-13    2,59E-11
ENSG00000197951 ZNF71   0,967458386 3,97E-23    5,59E-21
ENSG00000135736 CCDC102A    1,0619472932    9,57E-18    1,02E-15
ENSG00000162654 GBP4    2,502767742 1,02E-97    7,09E-95
ENSG00000164342 TLR3    1,0648394078    1,68E-16    1,62E-14
ENSG00000117226 GBP3    1,1214295893    2,49E-47    7,88E-45
ENSG00000178726 THBD    -1,4528817816   3,55E-25    5,62E-23
ENSG00000214530 STARD10 1,5633072958    1,11E-38    2,78E-36
ENSG00000138678 AGPAT9  -1,1430936762   5,60E-32    1,12E-29
ENSG00000150048 CLEC1A  1,2751911972    7,72E-55    2,87E-52
ENSG00000231925 TAPBP   1,3480413157    1,26E-68    5,52E-66
ENSG00000133401 PDZD2   2,3248274849    7,95E-40    2,08E-37
ENSG00000178078 STAP2   1,28193951  3,40E-23    4,80E-21
ENSG00000135932 CAB39   0,9256585597    1,46E-35    3,26E-33
ENSG00000159128 IFNGR2  0,9511059149    1,21E-34    2,61E-32
ENSG00000213886 UBD 7,6186044178    3,41E-22    4,51E-20
ENSG00000143457 GOLPH3L 0,9607766432    1,80E-39    4,63E-37
ENSG00000173391 OLR1    7,7114015901    5,57E-23    7,71E-21
ENSG00000156587 UBE2L6  0,8515373492    1,57E-16    1,53E-14
ENSG00000272269 RP11-500C11.3   1,6678950328    4,05E-66    1,70E-63
ENSG00000267607 CTD-2369P2.8    7,4805566417    1,05E-20    1,30E-18
ENSG00000010030 ETV7    3,5462544329    2,05E-25    3,29E-23
ENSG00000178038 ALS2CL  0,7803985197    1,34E-12    9,59E-11
ENSG00000154639 CXADR   -1,0564152322   1,54E-29    2,77E-27
ENSG00000165801 ARHGEF40    1,4957938646    1,09E-51    3,79E-49
ENSG00000171227 TMEM37  -1,9016765305   1,14E-16    1,12E-14
ENSG00000145779 TNFAIP8 1,2349523996    1,40E-55    5,28E-53
ENSG00000162616 DNAJB4  -0,6648872946   1,48E-19    1,73E-17
ENSG00000132530 XAF1    1,0866278536    9,62E-23    1,32E-20
ENSG00000130589 HELZ2   1,2062416729    8,37E-46    2,52E-43
ENSG00000119922 IFIT2   1,6562895595    2,72E-16    2,58E-14
ENSG00000152689 RASGRP3 1,2913579655    9,56E-31    1,82E-28
ENSG00000154721 JAM2    2,7582655566    1,60E-23    2,30E-21
ENSG00000124212 PTGIS   1,3607275428    7,75E-29    1,35E-26
ENSG00000125898 FAM110A 0,7699331901    5,45E-11    3,40E-09
ENSG00000132003 ZSWIM4  1,7616984729    1,40E-72    6,76E-70
ENSG00000153721 CNKSR3  1,581266048 8,85E-39    2,23E-36
ENSG00000119714 GPR68   1,6813999238    1,50E-15    1,35E-13
ENSG00000163121 NEURL3  4,8947295863    2,82E-18    3,10E-16
ENSG00000204261 TAPSAR1 1,7286495357    2,63E-22    3,53E-20
ENSG00000152784 PRDM8   1,3177095327    2,45E-23    3,50E-21
ENSG00000155130 MARCKS  0,3369290495    4,18E-07    1,60E-05
ENSG00000149212 SESN3   -0,9948166535   7,71E-13    5,65E-11
ENSG00000100368 CSF2RB  1,0499093721    5,70E-33    1,17E-30
ENSG00000143466 IKBKE   1,1726116768    3,24E-48    1,04E-45
ENSG00000167207 NOD2    4,1387725935    8,46E-24    1,26E-21
ENSG00000100678 SLC8A3  5,436416856 9,64E-17    9,51E-15
ENSG00000169085 C8orf46 3,9179192668    7,17E-28    1,23E-25
ENSG00000196776 CD47    1,0211094014    8,26E-44    2,40E-41
ENSG00000102934 PLLP    1,7574549603    3,20E-37    7,74E-35
ENSG00000160190 SLC37A1 0,8662438352    9,61E-17    9,51E-15
ENSG00000167191 GPRC5B  1,3510883965    5,59E-51    1,90E-48
ENSG00000178882 FAM101A 1,0828435301    1,93E-39    4,90E-37
ENSG00000104825 NFKBIB  0,8083231505    7,72E-22    1,01E-19
ENSG00000119801 YPEL5   0,8034326357    4,90E-26    8,03E-24
ENSG00000181634 TNFSF15 1,4304497633    2,37E-37    5,79E-35
ENSG00000129667 RHBDF2  1,1649981551    6,94E-44    2,05E-41
ENSG00000184602 SNN 0,7740862573    1,48E-20    1,81E-18
ENSG00000100365 NCF4    4,558251281 4,52E-24    6,78E-22
ENSG00000183018 SPNS2   0,8902983353    1,71E-29    3,07E-27
ENSG00000166949 SMAD3   1,2851538162    1,07E-71    4,98E-69
ENSG00000130066 SAT1    1,0984598053    4,24E-40    1,13E-37
ENSG00000110218 PANX1   1,0458454628    7,65E-29    1,34E-26
ENSG00000160179 ABCG1   1,1614780131    1,63E-33    3,40E-31
ENSG00000139899 CBLN3   1,7931732267    3,03E-33    6,29E-31
ENSG00000090776 EFNB1   1,0699057643    7,00E-41    1,91E-38
ENSG00000164400 CSF2    4,5542622849    2,10E-13    1,62E-11
ENSG00000175155 YPEL2   0,9464573628    2,72E-23    3,87E-21
ENSG00000003137 CYP26B1 -2,5718415447   3,28E-37    7,89E-35
ENSG00000205220 PSMB10  1,0292991652    3,63E-16    3,41E-14
ENSG00000079156 OSBPL6  -0,9160285066   2,97E-15    2,58E-13
ENSG00000196878 LAMB3   0,9332660731    2,34E-30    4,34E-28
ENSG00000251136 RP11-37B2.1 1,203718483 8,06E-11    4,92E-09
ENSG00000198832 SELM    1,321494591 1,58E-24    2,43E-22
ENSG00000164035 EMCN    -0,8736185363   1,02E-28    1,77E-26
ENSG00000166900 STX3    -0,869513786    3,29E-31    6,42E-29
ENSG00000141682 PMAIP1  0,8638748761    6,22E-29    1,09E-26
ENSG00000131669 NINJ1   0,8906736714    8,86E-26    1,44E-23
ENSG00000069399 BCL3    1,413913047 3,29E-46    1,00E-43
ENSG00000079102 RUNX1T1 -0,9911151505   2,07E-36    4,86E-34
ENSG00000227908 CTD-2031P19.3   2,3325227057    4,64E-17    4,65E-15
ENSG00000166224 SGPL1   0,8439625523    7,13E-25    1,11E-22
ENSG00000175183 CSRP2   0,8563780143    1,68E-12    1,20E-10
ENSG00000138675 FGF5    1,192502468 2,25E-25    3,60E-23
ENSG00000186827 TNFRSF4 5,8841358772    1,11E-17    1,18E-15
ENSG00000112299 VNN1    3,3660978538    1,64E-17    1,72E-15
ENSG00000178860 MSC 4,183307096 4,71E-14    3,78E-12
ENSG00000155324 GRAMD3  1,2255824988    6,50E-11    4,00E-09
ENSG00000185442 FAM174B -0,836626047    7,24E-22    9,49E-20
ENSG00000136883 KIF12   2,2885773567    1,13E-18    1,27E-16
ENSG00000235947 EGOT    6,7704547822    2,96E-12    2,03E-10
ENSG00000124721 DNAH8   -1,2678732696   2,92E-17    2,97E-15
ENSG00000159231 CBR3    1,5647327275    2,29E-52    8,13E-50
ENSG00000065491 TBC1D22B    0,8538972942    2,30E-26    3,80E-24
ENSG00000169242 EFNA1   1,4165954554    4,27E-40    1,13E-37
ENSG00000231360 AL592284.1  2,7073184262    4,36E-15    3,72E-13
ENSG00000221926 TRIM16  0,7029520377    3,73E-14    3,02E-12
ENSG00000272016 RP11-215G15.5   0,8117914573    1,13E-12    8,17E-11
ENSG00000151014 CCRN4L  1,0379114203    3,56E-24    5,36E-22
ENSG00000142961 MOB3C   0,997961002 3,26E-15    2,82E-13
ENSG00000171236 LRG1    2,3435370548    1,70E-15    1,49E-13
ENSG00000122861 PLAU    0,9088760584    8,82E-30    1,62E-27
ENSG00000127191 TRAF2   0,7563313941    4,45E-16    4,11E-14
ENSG00000175592 FOSL1   0,850193167 1,53E-30    2,88E-28
ENSG00000136842 TMOD1   2,1656895527    6,25E-17    6,25E-15
ENSG00000111801 BTN3A3  0,8389416662    3,24E-19    3,70E-17
ENSG00000048052 HDAC9   2,129043477 5,04E-34    1,07E-31
ENSG00000145911 N4BP3   1,4898252251    2,52E-29    4,48E-27
ENSG00000127472 PLA2G5  4,2086612089    3,06E-17    3,10E-15
ENSG00000146374 RSPO3   1,1440299676    8,21E-33    1,67E-30
ENSG00000165659 DACH1   -1,5561758479   7,59E-30    1,40E-27
ENSG00000213443 RP11-75L1.2 2,3331573508    7,07E-14    5,62E-12
ENSG00000162009 SSTR5   -2,7085099871   2,12E-13    1,63E-11
ENSG00000176697 BDNF    -1,0585506837   4,57E-16    4,21E-14
ENSG00000134531 EMP1    -0,4110928344   1,93E-09    1,04E-07
ENSG00000064932 SBNO2   0,7580102147    9,23E-22    1,19E-19
ENSG00000103241 FOXF1   0,9686198954    2,33E-16    2,24E-14
ENSG00000111859 NEDD9   0,9160581572    1,69E-26    2,83E-24
ENSG00000109079 TNFAIP1 0,9377237493    1,37E-36    3,27E-34
ENSG00000081059 TCF7    0,7092656194    3,96E-10    2,27E-08
ENSG00000171246 NPTX1   1,7377387028    1,22E-11    8,01E-10
ENSG00000204264 PSMB8   0,6716991695    1,59E-15    1,41E-13
ENSG00000106688 SLC1A1  -0,7863595313   2,43E-22    3,27E-20
ENSG00000034152 MAP2K3  0,6419097183    1,11E-17    1,18E-15
ENSG00000125089 SH3TC1  0,7289249819    3,83E-16    3,58E-14
ENSG00000073849 ST6GAL1 1,2554852844    1,42E-52    5,09E-50
ENSG00000100911 PSME2   0,7116652869    4,03E-15    3,45E-13
ENSG00000134470 IL15RA  1,102594557 1,21E-34    2,61E-32
ENSG00000145777 TSLP    2,4138779529    5,47E-13    4,04E-11
ENSG00000204682 CASC10  1,5144410531    8,14E-22    1,06E-19
ENSG00000095739 BAMBI   -0,7977061864   2,09E-11    1,35E-09
ENSG00000013297 CLDN11  0,4607939704    4,26E-12    2,89E-10
ENSG00000132274 TRIM22  0,677227739 1,44E-20    1,77E-18
ENSG00000163932 PRKCD   0,7708216872    1,26E-23    1,82E-21
ENSG00000221869 CEBPD   1,608895375 1,05E-29    1,93E-27
ENSG00000185361 TNFAIP8L1   0,7285886419    1,39E-21    1,78E-19
ENSG00000170689 HOXB9   1,8396661331    4,34E-21    5,44E-19
ENSG00000197646 PDCD1LG2    1,0196899604    1,21E-17    1,28E-15
ENSG00000164116 GUCY1A3 2,6004545429    4,70E-14    3,78E-12
ENSG00000184545 DUSP8   1,4675244694    1,17E-23    1,71E-21
ENSG00000117707 PROX1   -1,2550165503   4,12E-19    4,69E-17
ENSG00000137767 SQRDL   1,1255236894    1,74E-17    1,82E-15
ENSG00000071282 LMCD1   -0,9118384423   4,52E-14    3,65E-12
ENSG00000117525 F3  1,1822992014    5,09E-09    2,58E-07
ENSG00000127666 TICAM1  0,8064954922    2,30E-18    2,55E-16
ENSG00000107968 MAP3K8  1,4073405226    1,57E-22    2,13E-20
ENSG00000165685 TMEM52B 3,0865735935    4,16E-15    3,56E-13
ENSG00000126603 GLIS2   0,7834594541    7,02E-12    4,71E-10
ENSG00000143067 ZNF697  1,0177442557    9,12E-35    2,00E-32
ENSG00000100403 ZC3H7B  0,9618781013    9,95E-38    2,45E-35
ENSG00000149798 CDC42EP2    0,7806369468    6,07E-18    6,51E-16
ENSG00000169621 APLF    1,4855907744    8,43E-25    1,31E-22
ENSG00000206503 HLA-A   0,9350131142    9,76E-24    1,44E-21
ENSG00000113645 WWC1    2,2937570194    1,01E-16    9,89E-15
ENSG00000099250 NRP1    -0,5037267432   1,62E-12    1,16E-10
ENSG00000163719 MTMR14  0,5675343136    4,16E-13    3,10E-11
ENSG00000107821 KAZALD1 -1,4290087006   1,23E-11    8,07E-10
ENSG00000070404 FSTL3   1,1027505315    2,76E-29    4,87E-27
ENSG00000187210 GCNT1   -0,8686522938   4,71E-31    9,12E-29
ENSG00000133069 TMCC2   1,0413789794    1,68E-16    1,62E-14
ENSG00000131409 LRRC4B  1,2931498234    1,18E-10    7,13E-09
ENSG00000154451 GBP5    2,7013678594    1,83E-12    1,29E-10
ENSG00000166394 CYB5R2  0,7332646196    3,05E-12    2,09E-10
ENSG00000135114 OASL    2,1951538388    4,01E-11    2,55E-09
ENSG00000100342 APOL1   1,220028965 1,77E-35    3,93E-33
ENSG00000228536 RP11-392O17.1   2,7825337115    1,93E-09    1,04E-07
ENSG00000167034 NKX3-1  1,3585205916    2,32E-14    1,89E-12
ENSG00000185507 IRF7    0,8084085248    4,12E-08    1,85E-06
ENSG00000082641 NFE2L1  0,3652826186    2,25E-07    8,90E-06
ENSG00000187123 LYPD6   1,0308782093    3,26E-25    5,18E-23
ENSG00000174059 CD34    1,1102344592    7,81E-27    1,33E-24
ENSG00000178719 GRINA   0,8396601415    7,97E-24    1,19E-21
ENSG00000104213 PDGFRL  0,6828700248    1,96E-08    9,17E-07
ENSG00000149115 TNKS1BP1    0,7459528472    8,49E-22    1,10E-19
ENSG00000105499 PLA2G4C 1,3580795546    2,24E-23    3,20E-21
ENSG00000136048 DRAM1   0,7409353033    1,66E-24    2,52E-22
ENSG00000105327 BBC3    0,7261708499    7,85E-16    7,13E-14
ENSG00000125726 CD70    6,1411549057    4,39E-09    2,26E-07
ENSG00000136052 SLC41A2 1,4157227919    2,37E-40    6,38E-38
ENSG00000151883 PARP8   2,4975836849    2,04E-11    1,31E-09
ENSG00000102802 MEDAG   -0,9069167651   6,00E-18    6,46E-16
ENSG00000161791 FMNL3   0,8876008674    1,60E-24    2,45E-22
ENSG00000235505 RP11-693N9.2    1,3375439579    6,56E-22    8,63E-20
ENSG00000166592 RRAD    2,2813391338    1,28E-11    8,41E-10
ENSG00000011132 APBA3   0,8498271597    3,31E-21    4,18E-19
ENSG00000152778 IFIT5   0,788230332 2,76E-12    1,91E-10
ENSG00000146021 KLHL3   -1,1835895681   1,63E-20    1,97E-18
ENSG00000186918 ZNF395  -0,8474414144   5,73E-13    4,22E-11
ENSG00000141384 TAF4B   1,0663419997    7,55E-15    6,33E-13
ENSG00000261618 RP11-79H23.3    6,1379496776    6,43E-09    3,21E-07
ENSG00000176170 SPHK1   0,6840743548    9,03E-18    9,65E-16
ENSG00000178764 ZHX2    0,646055016 3,32E-08    1,50E-06
ENSG00000131323 TRAF3   0,9936331075    1,50E-31    2,96E-29
ENSG00000111077 TENC1   -0,8569865373   1,32E-26    2,22E-24
ENSG00000108688 CCL7    3,2634690098    5,88E-11    3,64E-09
ENSG00000185972 CCIN    1,4017678544    6,24E-14    4,99E-12
ENSG00000171056 SOX7    0,5167198577    1,05E-11    6,95E-10
ENSG00000173114 LRRN3   4,3283970118    3,29E-08    1,49E-06
ENSG00000157368 IL34    3,3547659657    8,97E-13    6,53E-11
ENSG00000104903 LYL1    -0,8418136115   3,07E-22    4,07E-20
ENSG00000019582 CD74    3,0129058195    4,82E-15    4,08E-13
ENSG00000105974 CAV1    0,2932091817    9,21E-06    0,0002734463
ENSG00000060982 BCAT1   -0,3791961842   1,23E-07    5,09E-06
ENSG00000140105 WARS    0,3678696708    1,29E-07    5,30E-06
ENSG00000185862 EVI2B   -0,7751849257   7,67E-13    5,63E-11
ENSG00000230024 RP11-95P13.1    2,2114928759    2,92E-10    1,70E-08
ENSG00000205683 DPF3    0,885344948 6,79E-25    1,06E-22
ENSG00000117298 ECE1    0,3157266591    3,07E-06    0,0001015302
ENSG00000167657 DAPK3   0,6431442219    2,12E-15    1,85E-13
ENSG00000137491 SLCO2B1 4,3274368507    4,19E-08    1,88E-06
ENSG00000113583 C5orf15 0,5402358913    3,06E-12    2,09E-10
ENSG00000270055 CTD-3092A11.2   0,7554364577    7,81E-19    8,85E-17
ENSG00000131979 GCH1    0,6475915098    2,22E-08    1,03E-06
ENSG00000133110 POSTN   -1,4607784203   2,54E-16    2,42E-14
ENSG00000258376 RP4-647C14.2    1,0759940117    6,92E-16    6,31E-14
ENSG00000138735 PDE5A   0,7694825617    1,09E-08    5,27E-07
ENSG00000130813 C19orf66    0,7515725796    6,83E-11    4,20E-09
ENSG00000068079 IFI35   0,6235697941    1,17E-07    4,85E-06
ENSG00000103966 EHD4    0,3296977083    1,76E-06    6,09E-05
ENSG00000068323 TFE3    0,6380042855    7,25E-17    7,20E-15
ENSG00000158286 RNF207  1,4669614441    9,13E-24    1,35E-21
ENSG00000185432 METTL7A -0,7584393281   1,33E-17    1,40E-15
ENSG00000115525 ST3GAL5 -0,773362582    2,49E-10    1,46E-08
ENSG00000157214 STEAP2  -0,8210679404   3,15E-16    2,98E-14
ENSG00000272567 RP11-73K9.3 2,9091368904    8,12E-09    3,98E-07
ENSG00000039560 RAI14   0,2386460603    0,0020376264    0,0294805528
ENSG00000138496 PARP9   0,7105625312    3,91E-17    3,94E-15
ENSG00000137509 PRCP    0,3733976516    4,28E-07    1,63E-05
ENSG00000165449 SLC16A9 1,9129485254    2,60E-09    1,37E-07
ENSG00000119508 NR4A3   2,5623582992    2,34E-08    1,08E-06
ENSG00000135842 FAM129A 1,5252436186    1,45E-50    4,79E-48
ENSG00000110077 MS4A6A  -1,8461966802   4,31E-13    3,21E-11
ENSG00000071575 TRIB2   -0,7680150878   4,23E-11    2,68E-09
ENSG00000125845 BMP2    0,7198947357    4,95E-23    6,91E-21
ENSG00000131459 GFPT2   0,9799396691    4,34E-34    9,30E-32
ENSG00000223749 MIR503HG    -0,7622227546   2,06E-07    8,18E-06
ENSG00000110330 BIRC2   0,9547055389    2,68E-36    6,15E-34
ENSG00000066697 MSANTD3 0,5051725739    4,29E-12    2,90E-10
ENSG00000119938 PPP1R3C -0,790560028    5,29E-11    3,32E-09
ENSG00000267194 RP1-193H18.2    -1,5145912925   2,28E-14    1,86E-12
ENSG00000241839 PLEKHO2 0,6124896724    2,15E-13    1,65E-11
ENSG00000175354 PTPN2   0,5466696999    2,50E-12    1,74E-10
ENSG00000134321 RSAD2   3,0393073451    1,92E-08    8,98E-07
ENSG00000106560 GIMAP2  0,5431526321    1,76E-08    8,31E-07
ENSG00000136514 RTP4    3,2781934027    3,06E-08    1,39E-06
ENSG00000157191 NECAP2  0,6570089291    2,01E-17    2,09E-15
ENSG00000108771 DHX58   0,7262618335    4,77E-08    2,10E-06
ENSG00000131203 IDO1    3,313005567 2,77E-08    1,27E-06
```

Comment: As already advised in previous question : create a minimal example  that anyone can copy and paste in their R environment to reproduce - and try to fix - your issue

Comment: But you will need my input file to make it work, that's why I did not do it. I will try to copy and paste it in the question as soon as I get home.

Comment: I did like you ask :). I hope someone will have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a part of your server code so that the image renders. Have a look at the code below:

```
observe({
      if (input$startkegg != 0) {


        kegg <- reactive({ enrichKEGG(entrezIDs(), pAdjustMethod=input$adjmk, pvalueCutoff=input$keggp, qvalueCutoff=input$keggq)})

        output$pathway1 <- renderImage({

          width  <- session$clientData$output_pathway1_width
          height <- session$clientData$output_pathway1_height
          #This is the file that will be saved
          outfile <- paste0(tempdir(),"\\",as.matrix(as.data.frame(kegg())[1])[1:1], ".png")


          #Save the file in the temp folder
          pathview(gene.data=entrezIDs(), pathway.id=as.matrix(as.data.frame(kegg())[1])[1:1],species = "hsa", 
                   limit=3,  kegg.dir = tempdir())
          # Pathview generates a png file (it is possible to generate many png at once by changing '[1:1]' by other numbers)


          list(src = outfile,
               contentType = 'image/png+xml',
               width = width,
               height = height,
               alt = "plotGoGraph")
        }, deleteFile  =FALSE)
      }
    })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works partially, thank you very much ! I had the image in the app, but if I change the parameters pvalue, qvalue, padjustmethod) or try to relaunch the App, I have the error : "Error in readPNG: file is not in PNG format". I must close and relaunch RStudio each time. Is there a missing reactive value somewhere ? Or a path which becomes wrong ?